# How to set a keyboard shortcut for toggling 'mouse keys' on/off in universal access, 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

Unfortunately this is not one of the default keyboard shortcuts than can be set with a command in 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the commands those controls this toggling from command line are

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable false
```

you can make a script for toggling of them like below.
i named it like Mouse Keys Toggling `MKT.sh` and stored on Desktop.

```
#!/bin/bash

key="org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable"
current=$(gsettings get $key)

if [ "$current" == "true" ]; then
  gsettings set $key false
else
  gsettings set $key true
fi
```

for toggling use the below command

```
bash /home/<user>/Desktop/MKT.sh
```

Change `<user>` with your user name.

[image]

Set custom shortcut for it as you wish.

go to keyboards, add new shortcut anything you wish.

[image]